# Can't install telegram using a repository i addded on KDE Neon

Tags: ubuntu, apt, kde, repository, kde-neon

Recently i got an update which broke telegram and now i can't install it using apt on my KDE Neon installation. It used to work perfectly fine before that.

I got the repo at this article
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/08/how-to-install-telegram-on-ubuntu
and I added it by using the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
```

Using the below command used to install it perfectly fine

```
$ sudo apt install telegram-desktop
```

but after some update i have been getting this error message and I don't understand why.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) telegram-desktop:amd64 < none -> 2.1.7+ds-2~ubuntu20.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken telegram-desktop:amd64 Depends on libopenal1:amd64 < none | 1:1.19.1-1 @un uH > (>= 1.14)
  Considering libopenal1:amd64 0 as a solution to telegram-desktop:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated libopenal-data:amd64
  Re-Instated libopenal1:amd64
Broken telegram-desktop:amd64 Depends on libqrcodegencpp1:amd64 < none | 1.5.0-2build1 @un uH > (>= 1.2.1)
  Considering libqrcodegencpp1:amd64 0 as a solution to telegram-desktop:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated libqrcodegencpp1:amd64
Broken telegram-desktop:amd64 Depends on librlottie0-1:amd64 < none | 0~git20200305.a717479+dfsg-1 @un uH > (>= 0~git20200305.a717479+dfsg)
  Considering librlottie0-1:amd64 0 as a solution to telegram-desktop:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated librlottie0-1:amd64
Broken telegram-desktop:amd64 Depends on libxxhash0:amd64 < none | 0.7.3-1 @un uH > (>= 0.6.5)
  Considering libxxhash0:amd64 0 as a solution to telegram-desktop:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated libxxhash0:amd64
Broken telegram-desktop:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-12-8:amd64 < none @un H >
  Considering libqt5core5a:amd64 3417 as a solution to telegram-desktop:amd64 9999
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 telegram-desktop : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-8
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: So what happens if you try to install the missing package? `apt install qtbase-abi-5-12-8`

Comment: maybe this might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210703/how-to-install-qtbase-abi-5-9-5-in-ubuntu-19-10 Greetinngs
kh

Comment: I gave up on this and installed using flatpak.

Answer (score 0):

### for install  missing dependencies when installing software use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

You try install program from default repository (`apt policy telegram-desktop`).
You should install **telegram**, not **telegram-desktop**.